# How can I display devexpress command button's caption below it's icon?

Tags: devexpress

I would like to use `CommandButton` on a devexpress form. I set the `.glyph` to a large image. Then I set the `PaintStyle` (only way I found to show the caption too) to `CaptionGlyph` value. It places the caption next to the Icon. How can I place it below the Icon (see left one as a LargeButton).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed only the `.command` from the `CommandButton`, so I decided to make a new component from an existing one: `BarLargeButtonItem` with implementation of `ISupportReportCommand`. Only problem with this, that I can put this on the form only by modifying the .designer.cs file, what is lamme, but works.

Here is the code in case someone else will need such thing:

```
using DevExpress.XtraBars;
using DevExpress.XtraReports.UserDesigner;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace StefaniaNET.Nyomtatvanyok.Komponensek
{
  public class Gomb : BarLargeButtonItem, ISupportReportCommand 
  {
    public Gomb()
    {
      #region alapbeállítások
      PaintStyle = BarItemPaintStyle.CaptionGlyph;
      CaptionAlignment = BarItemCaptionAlignment.Bottom;
      #endregion
    }

    #region ISupportReportCommand implementáció
    public ReportCommand Command { get; set; }

    //public ReportCommand Command
    //{
    //  get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    //}
    #endregion
  }
}
```